# Check many keys in dictionary: optimization

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Is there a better way to write the following:

```
if "msg" in response_dic or "save_act_errors" in response_dic  or "add_act_errors" in response_dic  or "modif_act_errors" in response_dic  or "update_act_errors" in response_dic:
    #do stuff
```

`response_dic` is a dictionary, I am checking for keys.

There are 2 questions in fact:

1/ How to test many keys in a dictionary?

2/ How to check partial keys (in my case finishing with "_act_errors")?

Comment: You're right, it's a similar problem, but in my situation I have to use any and not all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! there is a better way:

```
keys = ["msg", "save_act_errors", "add_act_errors", "modif_act_errors", ...]

if any(key in response_dic for key in keys):
    #do stuff
```

Comment: Good idea! It is shorter to write but is it as efficient?

Comment: The `any()` is doing exactly the same you were doing. It will stop and return `True` when it find the first expression that evaluates to `True`, otherwise will return `False`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> keys = ['msg','save_act_errors']
>>> d = { 'msg':1 }
>>> any(key in d for key in keys)
True
```

Or

```
>>> keys | set(d)
```

Comment: You need two `set`s for the `|` operator... and furthermore,  `set(keys) & set(d)` would make more sense!

Comment: The `any` operator is exactly what I need. But I think using a `set` would be slower, right?